# ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException: unknown command 'SCAN'

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I registered my RedisClient in my ServiceStack app host as follows

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new RedisManagerPool(conn));
container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient().WithPrefix("MyPrefix"));
```

however, in my Service when I call

```
var keys = Cache.GetAllKeys();
```

i received this error: ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException: unknown command 'SCAN'

how should I solve this? I would like to clear all keys in this CacheClient with the prefix setup in the container.

Comment: What version of redis are you using? SCAN is a relatively new command.

Comment: i'm using 2.4.6. I downloaded from https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads as i'm using windows

Comment: ok, so 2.4.6 is an ancient version, like 5-6 years old. And redis on windows isn't officially supported, I suggest you run docker and use a redis image on that.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an [extremely outdated version](https://redis.io/download) of Redis that doesn't implement the SCAN operations.

You can follow these instructions to [install a recent version of Redis on Windows](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows).